# XML Response Echoing to Screen Instead of Returning to Variable

Tags: php, xml

I have some PHP code, including an XML-generating and sending class that allows my business partners to send me information.  It's working like a dream, except for the response. It keeps printing the XML response to the screen.

Their PHP page (which I'm in control of), generates and sends (via CURL POST) the XML to my site's receiving PHP page, which processes the data (correctly) and echos an XML Success/Error response.  Even though I've tried capturing the response in a class variable or just returning it into a variable from their PHP page, it keeps showing the XML Response on the page and that won't work, it just needs to be processed programmatically.

Business Partner's PHP:

```
$hbn = new hbnXML;
$hbn->UpdateType = "Update";
$hbn->Populate($hbnData);

//echo "creating base<br>";
$hbn->createXMLBase();
//echo "createing XML<br>";
$hbn->createXML();
//echo "sending XML<br>";
$result = $hbn->sendXML();
// i want to process $result here
//echo "RESULT: $result<br>";
```

Pertinent class fxn:

```
   function sendXML(){
        $url = "http://mywebsite.com/receiveXML";
    //setting the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // Following line is compulsary to add as it is:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                "xmlRequest=" . html_entity_decode($this->xml, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if (!$result) {
                echo "<p>cURL error number: " .curl_errno($ch) . " on URL: " . $url ."</p>" . "<p>cURL error: " . curl_error($ch) . "</p>";
            }
            if($result && $result != "Success"){
               print $result;
            }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
```

}

receiveXML.php: line that prints XML response

```
if($update_id){
   header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
   echo genXMLResponse("Success",null);
}
```

Comment: I see a `print $result;` inside that last `if` block. That would do it, no?

Comment: If, that is, the purpose of the curl transaction is to retrieve XML.  You stored the `curl_exec()` into `$result`, which would then be the full XML, which you `print` if it isn't `== "Success"`

Comment: Remove print `$result`?? - Beat me to it @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Bless you and your eagle eyes.  That's what I get for being thorough and deciding to return an XML Response instead of just the word "Success."  I was going out of my mind!  Add an answer and I'll give you credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a simple oversight of a `print` statement.  The `curl_exec()` transaction returns the XML string into `$response`, which is printed if `$response != "Success"`.  If it indeed contains XML, `$response` will probably *never* be `== "Success"`, and therefore always be printed.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// You already handled errors here, $result contains XML.
if (!$result) {
   echo "<p>cURL error number: " .curl_errno($ch) . " on URL: " . $url ."</p>" . "<p>cURL error: " . curl_error($ch) . "</p>";
}

// Remove this block..
// if($result && $result != "Success"){
//   print $result;
// }
```